# div not firing onclick event in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

my div element is :

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

below is javascript.:

```
function makediv() {
        var divmy = document.getElementById("div");
        var row ='';
        var color='#ccc';
        for(var i=0;i<2;i++) 
        {
divmy.innerHTML += " <div class='dynamic' id='inner"+i+"' onclick=searchFilterations(i)>"+i+"</div> ";
            color='black';
        }
    }
    function searchFilterations(e){
    alert(e);
    }
```

problem is: searchFilterations() function not firing on click.what is the error?
here is fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/cjT4s/4/

Comment: Wrong settings in jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/cjT4s/6/

Comment: see [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/cjT4s/8/). setting wrap in body option will make it work or bind it to on body load.

Comment: thanks ,it works,what was the wrong setting..can u tell me?

Comment: Remove ----Bilal---- and it will work on your jsfiddle too!!

Comment: on left second dropdown select wrap in body option instead onLoad.

Comment: In jsFiddle, when using the onload or domReady options, the code is wrapped in a function so the `searchFilterations` function is out of scope as it's no longer in the global scope, which is what you need with inline event handlers.

Comment: ok thanks zaheer. and all above

Answer (score 0):

Please call `makediv` function `onload` event

```
window.onload = makediv;

function makediv() {
    var divmy = document.getElementById("div");
    var row ='';
    var color='#ccc';
    for(var i=0;i<2;i++) 
    {    

    //    divmy.innerHTML += " <div style='width: 100px;height: 30px;background-color:"+color+" ;' onclick=javascript:alert("+i+")></div> ";

         divmy.innerHTML += " <div class='dynamic' id='inner"+i+"' onclick=searchFilteration("+i+")>"+i+"</div> ";
        color='black';
    }
}
function searchFilteration(i){
alert(i);
}
```

[<kbd>FIDDLE DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/jangidgirish/cjT4s/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `window.searchFilteration = function (i) { ... }`:

```
makediv();

function makediv() {
    var divmy = document.getElementById("div");
    var row ='';
    var color='#ccc';
    for(var i=0;i<2;i++) 
    {    
         divmy.innerHTML += " <div class='dynamic' id='inner"+i+"' onclick='searchFilteration("+i+")'>"+i+"</div> ";
        color='black';
    }
}
window.searchFilteration = function (i){
alert(i);
}
```

[<kbd>FIDDLE DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/cjT4s/12/)